# "Cannot find symbol" error in the client code of an ejb application

Tags: java, ejb

I am new to EJB and trying to develop an application to find sum of two numbers remotely.First,i created an interface and then the bean class and then the client.
The interface `Adder.java`  gets compiled but compiling the bean class `AdderBean.java`  gives the following error.

```
C:\Users\Asad\Desktop\EJB>javac AdderBean.java
AdderBean.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
 class AdderBean implements Adder
                            ^
  symbol: class Adder
1 error
```

But i have declared the interface `Adder.java` ,then why it's giving this error.

Adder interface

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Adder
{
     int add(int x,int y);
}
```

Bean Class Code

AdderBean.java

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless(mappedName="myAdder")
 class AdderBean implements Adder
{
    @PostConstruct  
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("post create");

    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }
    public int add(int x,int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }

}
```

Comment: `AdderBean` does not have `import` statement for `Adder` OR are these in the same package?

Comment: Both java files are in the same folder,then also do i need to import Adder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem with setting of classpath.Just before compiling these classes,i set the classpath to a jar file `api.jar` which was present in some other folder.That's why JVM wasn't able to find my interface `Adder.java`.Problem solved now.